# flask user authentication - and cname setup of jupyter notebook via apache

Tags: flask, ipython, jupyter, cname

This is the challenge. My domain hosts a simple page on www.mydomain.com for everyone to see, on admin.mydomain.com it serves a flask app with user authentication for partners/clients.  My ipython jupyter notebook serves by default on startup on mydomain.com:8888, for which I created a CNAME record dev.mydomain.com that points to the jupyter notebook (mydomain.com:8888)

Right now anyone can go to dev.mydomain.com and access the ipython notebook. 
I want to create a link for developers that are logged in the admin dashboard to dev.mydomain.com (to access ipython notebook),this way making the dev.mydomain.com only accessible if you have credentials to admin.mydomain.com (like using the @is_logged_in decorator in flask for normal dashboard pages but make it for dev.mydomain.com)

I know that with jupyter notebook a password protected environment is available but there isn't a user option, that's why i am ignoring this solution for the moment.

Help would be greatly appreciated.